How can write a test for server side data fetching in react Ag-grid?
I am using react ag-grid library and looking to write a unit test for server side data fetching.
As it is clear in the following code, the getRowData is defined at userOption(gridOption) and then passed as a prop of Agrid component.
const options: RhGridOptions = {
        stateManagerId: "userListGrid",
        initLoading: true,
        paginationPageSize: 4,
        cacheBlockSize: 4,
        getRowId: (rowData) => rowData.data?.id,
        getServerRows: (params: any) => {
            userListGridRef.current?.showLoading();
            paginationConfig.current.page = params.page;
            paginationConfig.current.size = params.rowsPerPage;
            service.getUser(
                paginationConfig.current,
                (res: any) => {
                    const data = res.data.content;
                    params.success(data, res.data.totalElements);
                },
                () => {
                    userListGridRef.current?.hideLoading();
                }
            );
        }
    };

How can i write a test for getServersRows method?
